# Can not set Sorted ASC Index on primary key field in oracle

Tags: oracle, indexing, primary-key, sorting

When I try to add a sorted ASC index on the field MyId the oracle sql developer tool says:

```
Index MyIdSortedIndex is defined identically to constraint PK_MyTable


CREATE TABLE MyTable 
   (    "MyId" NVARCHAR2(50), 
    "DESCRIPTION" NVARCHAR2(200), 
     CONSTRAINT "PK_MyTable" PRIMARY KEY ("MyId")  
   )
```

How can I set a sorted ASC index on my tables Primary Key MyId in Oracle ?

Comment: Why are you using mixed case names like "MyId"?  It causes a lot of inconvenience in Oracle unless there is a good reason why you need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is telling you that you don't need a new index, because you already have an index called "PK_MyTable" on "MyId" in ascending order.  When you add a primary key constraint to a table Oracle automatically adds an index of the same name to help enforce it, indexing the columns of the constraint in ascending order (since ascending is the default direction).

If you don't want to use the index Oracle created automatically you can do this:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable 
   (    "MyId" NVARCHAR2(50), 
    "DESCRIPTION" NVARCHAR2(200), 
   );

CREATE INDEX MyIdSortedIndex ON MyTable ("MyId" ASC);

ALTER TABLE MyTable Add CONSTRAINT "PK_MyTable" PRIMARY KEY ("MyId");
```

Since your index already exists when the primary key is added Oracle will use that instead of creating its own.

Comment: there is no additional index that I can see in the oracle sql developer tool created by oracle. MyId can`t be indexed in a sorted or else I would get my data returned in a sorted way. What it is telling me literally: "Index MyIdSortedIndex is defined identically to constraint PK_MyTable ".

Comment: There must be, because (a) you cannot have a primary key constraint without an index, and (b) Oracle says there is!  You do not get data returned sorted in any particular way just because an index exists, you only get data sorted in a particular way if you specify an ORDER BY clause in the select statement.

Comment: @TonyAndrews, in response to your (a) is it not possible (highly improbable though!) that someone might have created a PK and then dropped the index? So you could have a PK without an index?

Comment: @Ollie, I don't think so because Oracle won't let you drop an index that is being used to enforce a primary key.

Comment: + 1 exactly. A primary key is automatically indexed.

Comment: if my primary key is automatically indexed, why do I get my data unsorted? I do not want to set on every select a ORDER BY ASC. I want to do it per tables basis.

Comment: @Pascal, sorry but you can't, that's just a fact of life.  An index is a device that helps Oracle to answer queries efficiently, it does not impose an order on all select statements.

Comment: @Tony but why do I see in my oracle sql developer tool a index-ASC-sort thing which I can put on a certain field?

Comment: @Tony ok i guess this setting is only when I created my PK initially to set an index sorted ASC on it?

Comment: @Pascal, that is a SQL Developer gadget that adds an ORDER BY clause to the query it runs to show the data.  It can be set on any column whether indexed or not (but may work faster on indexed columns).  By default it will show the data by running a query like "SELECT * FROM MyTable"; when you specify a sort order on a column ity modifies its query to "SELECT * FROM MyTable ORDER BY col1"

Comment: @Tony So can I not use this 'gadget' for my own create table scripts? Which I select data from in my c# application? So I need to put on all my c# select statements a order by asc? Is that true?

Comment: @Pascal, yes you need to add ORDER BY to all select statements you run where you need the results to be ordered.  Note that if you are processing data rather than displaying it you may **not** need it ordered, and it may be work faster if you don't order the data then.